# How to join tables in different database on the same Sybase server

Tags: database, join, sybase, sap-ase, multiple-databases

Am working on Sybase ASE 15.5.

I have 2 databases created in the same server, "DatabaseA" and "DatabaseB". The database owner is "User".

Logging in as "User" I created a table in "DatabaseB", called "TableA".

Now, my user has access to both database, but the default database is "DatabaseA".

This is sucessful when i login to DatabaseA:

```
USE DatabaseB
GO
SELECT * from DatabaseB.User.TableA
GO
```

But this is not:

```
USE DatabaseA
GO
SELECT * from DatabaseB.User.TableA
GO
```

It tells me that there is "No such object or user exists in the database".

I have Googled and most sites say that if the user has rights, then you only need to append the database and owner name to the table to access it. But it does not seems to work for my case.

I have tried creating a non DBO user "User2", and assigning it select rights using

```
GRANT SELECT ON DatabaseB.User.TableA to User2
```

and sp_helprotect shows that the rights is there for this user. But the results are exactly the same as when i query it with User.

Below is the result from sp_helprotect

```
grantor | grantee | type    | action   | object   | column | grantable
'User'  | 'User2' | 'Grant' | 'Select' | 'TableA' | 'All'  | 'FALSE'
```

Is there anything configuration or setting that needs to be checked to enable this?

**EDIT (22 July 2015)**

Just discovered something. There are a few tables with DatabaseB that i can access from DatabaseA, but not all tables.

For example, there is TableA, TableB, TableC, and TableD in DatabaseB. Out of which TableB and TableD can be queried from DatabaseA using

```
USE DatabaseA
GO
SELECT * from DatabaseB.User.TableB
GO
SELECT * from DatabaseB.User.TableD
GO
```

which is sucessful. And

```
USE DatabaseA
GO
SELECT * from DatabaseB.User.TableA
GO
SELECT * from DatabaseB.User.TableC
GO
```

fails.

Help!!!

Comment: The middle part is a *'schema'*, not a *'user'* - does sybase create a schema-per-user? Because if not then that schema might not exist .. normally the default schema is named "dbo" or "public" or similar.

Comment: If I log in to DatabaseB directly and run the exact same SQL, it works. It just does not work when i log into DatabaseA and try to query the table from there.

Both database are within the same server, and the user has access rights to them.

Comment: 'schema' is not ASE terminology (it's MS SQL Server terminology). That middle part is the database user name, aka. object owner.

Answer (score 2):

try  `SELECT * from DatabaseB..TableA` to fetch the result from different database

also you can do below

```
use DatabaseB
SELECT * from TableA
```

you must at least have read access to the database .

Just another example :
Just another example:

```
select tabA.*,tabC.* from DatabaseB..TableA tabA, DatabaseA..TableC tabC
where tabA.xxx = tabC.xxx
```

Comment: Yes the user has read access to both databases. I can issue the use statement to switch between the databases with a session, and query them individually. I just cannot query them from the other database, using the fully quantified table names.

Comment: You  don't have to use fully qualified name. just use `..` as my first example

Just another example:

`select tabA.*,tabC.* from DatabaseB..TableA tabA, DatabaseA..TableC tabC
where tabA.xxx = tabC.xxx`

Comment: Have just tested using the `..`. The result is still not working. Is there anything i need to configure in the server to allow cross database selects?

Comment: can you write your complete query ?

Comment: See the question. That is my complete query. Only the database and table names are sanitized.

Comment: Same error "No such object or user exists in the database"

Comment: May be the user permission is messed up. Can you check permission on the tables using `sp_helprotect TABLENAME`.

Comment: sp_helprotect returned zero rows. Do i need to grant any rights? The user is the table owner.

Comment: May be you need to grant select permission on the user group from which the user belongs for the tables. try this again
`use DatabaseB
sp_helprotect TableA`

another thing can you do for me ?
When you just do `USE DatabaseA` what is the result ?

Comment: When i `use DatabaseB` the run `sp_helprotect TableA`. Zero rows are returned.

Comment: If i `use DatabaseA` there is no problem. As I said, User is the owner or both database, as well as the owner of the table in question.

Comment: TableA in DatabaseB has no select permission it seems , grant select permission to the table for that user group/user and then try and see the result.

Comment: When i try to grant full permission to the user from the SAP Control Center, nothing happens. No rows are added to the result of sp_helpprotect. I guess that would be logical, seeing that the user is already the owner of the object.

Comment: Log in to the server (from client ie. sql advantage/sqlBrowser) with a       dbo user and  select `DatabaseB` and  execute
`grant select
on TableA
to USER`

Comment: If a table has any permission for any user it should return from `sp_helprotect`

Comment: The user I am using to query from both databases is already the database owner. No matter how many times i run the grant command, it will not assign extra rights to my user.

Comment: I have tested by creating another user and granting the rights to that user. But the results is the same. See the edits to the original question.

Comment: `GRANT SELECT ON DatabaseB.User.TableA to User2` why are you insisting on using `User`. in sybase we normally use `dbo`. Did you ran your query using `..`

Comment: Yes. Tried that. And tried dbo. Both does not work. Besides the table is created by User. There is no table created by dbo. When i `select * from User.TableA` in DatabaseB, it works, but not `select * from dbo.TableA`.

Comment: can you do a `sp_who USER` and see if loginame and origname is diff or not ?

Comment: Wanted to help you,but now don't see any way :(

Comment: Basically every web site i googled says as long as the user has access rights to the databases, and the tables, and they are in the same server, thet user should be able to access the tables using the fully quantified table name of `[database].[owner].[tablename]`. I have been trying for days and still cannot get it to work. Sad

Comment: Can you do a little experement ? create table with default schema(don't specify any schema[owner here in sybase]) and try your query

Comment: run this `select * from sysusers where uid < 16384 and name =USER` in both database. in sybase database ->user[schema]->table

Comment: For both I get `6, 3, 0,'User'`

Answer (score 0):

The ASE server login seems to be 'User' -- a login is the thing that needs a password. This is not the same as the database user inside a database. THis mapping is established with 'sp_adduser'.

To resolve your problem, you need to figure out which DB user you are. 
Run the following:

```
use DatabaseA
go
select user_name() user_in_A, suser_name() login_name
go

use DatabaseB
go
select user_name() user_in_B, suser_name() login_name
go
```

The output of these queries should help you move forward.

Comment: In this case, all the values returned are "User".

Comment: Actually that is not the actual user name i am using in my production, this is a sanitized version of it, but the results are all the same as the user name i am logged in with.

Comment: In that case,it means you have a server login called 'User' which is mapped to a DB user also named 'User' in each database (the latter two are independent).
Now if you create a table 'Mytab', it will technically be 'User.Mytab' -- run "sp_help 'User.Mytab'" to verify (all case-sensitive!).
You yourself can access the table either as  'User.Mytab' or as 'Mytab'. Other users must specify 'User.Mytab' (but they must be granted access permissions too). Ifyou refer to 'dbo.Mytab', this is an entirely different table, owner by the user who owns the database ('dbo').

Answer (score -1):

Having a login and user caled "USER" is not a good idea as it is also the name of the system function that returns the name of the current user. Can you try the same query using a different user altogether (eg. "bob")?

You may need to grant the appropriate permissions to bob but at least there won't be any confusion about user names.

This is further to RobV's comments (I don't have enough rep to add comments though!)

Comment: The actual user used is not "User". I have renamed the database, tables, and user names for security reasons. Whet you see is a sanitized version of the actual query.

Comment: Are you able to apply permissions to the table using roles? This will be set at the server level and will ensure it is the same in both databases.

Comment: I have tried user or role rights. Both does not work. Beside, the user is the database owner of both database as well as all the tables in both databases. I can switch between the database and query all the tables. I just cannot cross query the tables out from other tables.

Comment: As my suggestions get more desperate.... what happens if you query both tables from a third database (eg. tempdb)? Assuming role permissions again, that may highlight a problem in one database or the other if you can't access it.

Comment: Tried this and its the same.